# Group data by frequency

Tags: php

I am trying create a trending system that displays which keywords are trending by checking the occurrence of their usage.  I have able to get the count of occurences of the keywords into an array like this

```
$keyword_occurences = array("pheed"=>5, "php"=>7, "love" => 700);
```

How do I display this in descending order of occurrence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using functions `asort` and/or `arsort` to sort an associative array by values.

Answer (score 3):

Give [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) a go. You can specify `SORT_NUMERIC` to sort an array numerically. There are other array sorting functions [here](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).

---

On second thoughts, [`asort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) might be better, considering it maintains indexes. I haven't used them with an associative array like yours, so I don't know how both functions will behave, but one should work.

Comment: I don't think sort would work, it's an associative array. asort would be more appropriate

Comment: The most correct one will be arsort as it sorts in reverse order (desc)

Comment: @Ben I may have been editing my question as you typed your comment. I included `asort()` before you posted.